# $J＝R \otimes_K L$ implies, for arbitrary nonzero $α∈J$, there exists $r∈R$ and nonzero $β∈K$ such that $αr＝β$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, tensor-products

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $J$ be a field of fraction of $R$.
Let $K$ be an integral domain and $L$ be field of fraction of $K$.

Then, we further suppose $J＝R \otimes_K L$

In this situation, why can we say the following ?

> For arbitrary nonzero $α∈J$, there exists $r∈R$ and nonzero $β∈K$ such that $αr＝β$ ?

we can take such $α$ and $β∈R$ is trivial, but how can we take $β$ from $K$ ?

I may forget some important fact about tensor product and change of rings.Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, I don't assume such an assumption.

Comment: J＝R \otimes L is assumption, if we assume these assumptions, why can we say αr＝β, is my question.